# Using SSH socket inside Docker container on macOS when container is running as non-root user

Tags: docker, macos, ssh

I want to use my SSH Agent in my Docker container, as I need to pull some dependencies from private repositories during runtime. The container is only used for development. This works fine on Linux and Windows, but on macOS I either fail to mount the socket entirely or the connection gets refused.

From my testing, VirtioFS doesn't seem to work at all for sockets (?). With gRPC Fuse I can mount the socket and `ssh-add -l` gives me the correct identities. As soon as I change the container to run as a non-root user, I get "Permission denied", but I need to run the application inside my container as a specific user.

I tried to specify the source path to the SSH Socket as in `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` (`/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.xxxxxxx/Listeners`) and using the magic `/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock`.

The access flags for the socket inside the container is `srwxr-xr-x`, with root as owner, no matter how the flags or ownership of the socket is in the host file system.

To reproduce, this is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ssh

ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000
RUN groupadd --gid=${GID} appuser && \
    useradd --shell=/bin/bash --create-home --home-dir=/home/appuser --gid=${GID} --uid=${UID} --no-log-init appuser

CMD ["bash", "-c", "id && ls -l $SSH_AUTH_SOCK && ssh-add -l" ]
```

And this is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  test:
    build: .
    user: 1000:1000
    volumes:
      - /run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock:/ssh-agent
    environment:
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
```

When I comment the `user` attribute, the socket works.

So I think what I need is to either:

- change the owner of the socket inside the container (which I don't know how to do when the container is running as non-root user and the socket is only available during runtime and not while building)
- change the permissions (or use an ACL) to the socket (same issue)

Answer (score 0):

if you're already running as a non-root user, it's too late. but you can modify the permissions on the linux VM beforehand and then run your non-root container:

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4242#issuecomment-604890394

`docker run -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh -c 'chmod o+w /run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock'`